# Implementation of survey using surveyor gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, surveyor-gem

I am trying to implement a survey using the surveyor gem in rails. I want to make use of the user id to keep track of which user creates the survey and which user gave what response on which survey.

The problem is that I did not use the Devise gem for my user signin and signup. I built it manually. The surveyor gem uses a helper method current_user of Devise which returns details about the current user.

Since, I did not use devise, I am not sure where to add the helper method current_user.

I am not really sure as to what code to post, so please comment the required details. I will edit my post as needed.

Thanks!

application_controller.rb

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :authorize
helper_method :current_user
protected
  def authorize
    return true if ((self.class == SessionsController)|| (self.class == UsersController && (self.action_name == "new" || self.action_name == "create")))
    unless (User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]))
        redirect_to url_for(:controller => :sessions , :action => :new), alert: "You need to be logged in."
    end
   end

def current_user
    @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
end
end
```

Here is the link of the surveyor gem controller which uses the current_user method: https://github.com/kjayma/surveyor_gui/blob/master/app/controllers/surveyor_gui/survey_controller.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution to implement a `current_user` method.

[`helper_method`](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method) would make the `current_user` method available in every controller, which inherits from `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController

  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: I did. I added the current_user method under the protected methods in Application controller. But this method is not being used. This I know because I intentionally misspelled User.find() to User.kind() and it still shows no error. Any idea what the problem might be? I am editing my question to provide the application controller. And I do make sure that the user is logged in before taking the survey. Hence session[:user_id] can never be null in this case.

Comment: Add it to `before_filter`,so that it is being set: `before_filter :current_user`